# Clickonce issue when attempting to install application

Tags: windows, installation, clickonce, windows-iot-core-10

When I attempt to install the following app:
http://www.echolink.org/downloads/ES_SETUP21.EXE

It keeps trying to install the Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard which is unrelated to ES_SETUP21.exe and something I had installed a week ago. When I go to task manager, the ES_SETUP21.exe is not present but ClickOnce is. I have searched online for 2 days for something that can get me headed in the right direction but alas my find-fu ignorance prevails.

When I execute ES_SETUP21.exe:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiCNV.png)

Click  "Install anyway"

Then the User Account Control pops up stating:
"Do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make changes to your device", click "Yes".. normal so far..

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzBLJ.png)

Click "Setup" then this briefly appears on screen:

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky7KY.png)

Then this is where it goes wrong, this window appears.

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw3VI.png)

This is most definitely not what is expected. When I choose "Don't install" it just stops the installation and nothing further happens. If I choose "Install" it continues with the Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard". Can someone please help me step through and find whats happening here?" Thank you.

I am using Windows 10 Home. The ES_SETUP21.exe installed fine on my Win7 machine.

I have searched in the registry and default apps, nothing I can find changes the result.

Comment: Adding procmon export 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1hH_6Mk53NYZzrbMKb5bFWQssXHZ4iO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Issue resolved. Stepped through procmon export with blind ignorance and noticed that the setup was extracting and attempting to install files from the downloads folder. Moved the ES_SETUP21.exe file to a separate folder and the installation worked as it should. Not sure why it did this, but it did. 

Issue can be marked as resolved.

Comment: Turns out the installation was extracting a setup.exe file into the downloads directory and there was already one there, the Win 10 iot core dashboard installation file.